# How to delete columns of a series in InfluxDB

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

Is there any solution to remove a specific column of a series in InfluxDB?

Its seems that this feature is not implemented. But does anybody have found any kind of trick to do that?

Comment: In case anyone wants a work around with influxdb 2 to avoid selecting some columns, it's called `drop`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614957/2398593

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to delete a "column" (i.e. a field or a tag) from an Influx measurement. Here's the [feature request for that](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6150).

You'll have to SELECT INTO a different measurement, excluding the columns you don't want:

```
SELECT useful_field, nice_tag INTO new_measurement FROM measurement
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit stale, but Influx *still* does not have this feature.  We can only speculate about why not.

As I mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309049/how-to-delete-the-field-from-measurment-influxdb/76068477#76068477) question, though, since Influx just uses binary files for data and metadata you "just" have to figure out the formatting to edit these files.  Luckily, it seems some people have already done this for you.  In my search, I found [Infix](https://github.com/Abc-Arbitrage/infix), from ABC Arbitrage, which provides a command-line tool to rename, remove, and modify columns on Influx database files. The drawback is that it requires stopping the Influx service, so if you have a system that is not tolerant of downtime, you may still be out of luck.

Answer (score -3):

Probably too late, but you can use

```
USE table_name, DROP SERIES FROM "my_column_name"
```

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/manage-database/#drop-series-from-the-index-with-drop-series

Comment: This does not work. DROP SERIES FROM expects a measurement name, not a field key.