# How to delete field for a given measurement from influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I created multiple fields to test output in grafana, however I want to delete the unwanted fields from influxdb, is there a way?

Comment: There is a useful answer on this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767148/how-to-delete-columns-of-a-series-in-influxdb/

Answer (score 3):

**Q:** I want to delete the unwanted fields from influxdb, is there a way?

**A:** Short answer. No. Up until the latest release 1.4.0, there is no straightforward way to do this.

The reason why this is so was because `Influxdb` is explicitly designed to optimise point creation. Thus functionalities for the "UPDATE" and "DELETE" side of things are compromised for it.

To drop fields of a given measurement, the easiest way would be to;

1. `Retrieve` the data out first
2. `Modify` its content
3. `Drop` the measurement
4. `Re-insert` the modified data back

**Reference:**

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/concepts/insights_tradeoffs/