# How to delete the field from measurment Influxdb

Tags: database, influxdb, influxql

I am doing POC on influx db and i can see that if i am trying to drop measurement then all the data from the measurement has been deleted bu the old fields still remains there.

I want to delete the old fields how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

It was already answered: [How to delete columns of a series in InfluxDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767148/how-to-delete-columns-of-a-series-in-influxdb/)

You can't.

Here is a feature request for this and some workarounds: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6150

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2023, this is not possible (not easy, convenient, or safe, anyway) with the tools that Influx provides.  However, at the end of the day, the data is just stored in files that can be manipulated once the Influx service is down.

I recommend trying some reputable third-party tools or extensions.  One that I stumbled across was [Infix](https://github.com/Abc-Arbitrage/infix), from ABC Arbitrage. This repository provides a command-line tool to rename, remove, and modify columns on Influx database files.  The drawback is that it requires stopping the Influx service, so if you have a system that is not tolerant of downtime, you may still be out of luck.