# What is the equivalent of SELECT <certain columns> in Flux Query Language?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

What would be equivalent flux query for `SELECT address, name FROM addresses` ? (I am referring to FluxQL, the new query language developed by InfluxData)

I didn't find a clear answer to this in the limited Flux Documentation present. Flux documentation says that `filter()` function is the equivalent of both `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, but all examples given are equivalent of `WHERE` clauses, nothing on `SELECT`.

These are the documentation for FluxQL for better reference:

https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.50/introduction/getting-started

https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/query-data/get-started/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe you need something like this:

```
filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "addresses" and (r._field == "address" or r._field == "name"))
|> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey:["_field"], valueColumn:"_value")
|> drop(columns:["_value", ...])
```

in the "drop" (instead of ...) you can list all excesses columns

Comment: Drop is what I was looking for, thanks! however what purpose if pivot serving in this case?

Comment: After "filter" function, you get table with columns: _time, _value, _measurement and _field. It does not have columns "address" or "name" cause they are values in _field column. The function "pivot" transforms you're "filter" result in a table with column "address" and "name" (also with columns _time and _measurement).
See [doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.50/stdlib/built-in/transformations/pivot/)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to drop `result` and `table` columns? Dropping `_start`, `_stop` and `_measurement` columns works fine, but I cannot drop these two columns.

Comment: hi @l.sypniewski
I'm not sure you can do it cause result and table are the metadata of your request

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to use keep(colums...) function.
Unlike a drop, it takes the names of the columns to be left as arguments, and removes the rest.
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/keep/

Comment: "keep() returns a stream of tables containing only the specified columns". keep is better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map() function to select which column to keep and maybe do some string manipulation:

```
(from and filter part...)
|> map(fn: (r) => ({
                     address: r.address,
                     name: r.name
                   }))
```